# Leaflet only show europe

Tags: leaflet, layer

I just want show in the leaflet map europe and only let users draw and show layers in europe. Can be posible? How to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give some detail? With which url did you add the tile layer? Are you sure map styles are loaded correctly?

Comment: I'm gonna say [`maxBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-maxbounds).

Comment: You can also set up your own server/servers with maps and show only what is necessary, example - [only Poland](https://www.pkt.pl/szukaj/meble?viewType=map)

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzT. How can I achieve that in poland? Can you share some code? I have a GJson with europe pints and I show the layers.

Comment: @chetex As I wrote, the map server only serves tiles for Poland. This can't be done with geojson or some plugin :) (serving-tiles)[https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/]